# Errors after upgrading from fullCalendar 2.6.1 to 3.4.0

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I upgraded `fullCalendar.js` from `v2.6.1` to `v3.4.0` and now calendar displayed `undefined` with title and events time.

Also there is an issue with month view too. When I click on month view it displays error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: specialTokens[fakePart.substring(...)] is not a function
```

Comment: Can you include a relevant code sample? there's a pretty nifty [snippet feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) on SO that allows you to clearly illustrate the issue.

Comment: Issue resolved by including fullcalendar.js & scheduler.min.js after moment.js